# LockGuard for MFC CMutex

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I upgrade an old MFC multi-threaded C++ project (from year 2002) to VS2017 Windows 10 x64. I rewrote the mutex sections (MFC's `CMutex m_mu`). I preferred, of course, to use C++11 `std::mutex m_mutex` and `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex)` but it throws an exception. I decided to add my own `CLockGuard` class (code below).

**Example:** (m_mutex is a protected MFC `CMutex` member of `CMonitorsManager`)

```
void CMonitorsManager::OnMonitorLoginMessageArrive
                        (CMonitorLoginMessage* pMessage)
{
    CLockGuard LockGuard(&m_mutex);

    m_MonitorId2IPMap.SetAt(pMessage->GetDeviceAddress(),
                            pMessage->GetPeerAddress());
};
```

**LockGuard.h file:**

```
#pragma once

#include <afxmt.h>//for CMutex

class CLockGuard
{
public:
    CLockGuard(CMutex* rMutex);
    ~CLockGuard();

    void Unlock();

protected:
    CMutex* m_pMutex = nullptr;
};
```

**LockGuard.cpp file:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LockGuard.h"

CLockGuard::CLockGuard(CMutex* pMutex)
{
    pMutex->Lock();

    m_pMutex = pMutex;
}

void CLockGuard::Unlock()
{
    m_pMutex->Unlock();
    m_pMutex = nullptr;
}

CLockGuard::~CLockGuard()
{
    if (m_pMutex)
        m_pMutex->Unlock();
}
```

Comment: You could make it a template class, to be more generic (similar as `std::lock_guard`).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of writing your own `lock_guard`-like object specifically to use with a CMutex, I'd write a wrapper for CMutex to give it the `Lockable` interface, then just use it with a normal `std::lock_guard`:

```
namespace mfc {
class mutex {
    CMutex m;
public:
    mutex(BOOL bInitiallyOwn = FALSE,  
          LPCTSTR lpszName = NULL,  
          LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpsaAttribute = NULL) 
        : m(bInitiallyOwn, lpszName, lpsaAttribute) 
    {}

    void lock() { m.Lock(); }
    void unlock() { m.Unlock(); }
};
```

Then you can just lock it like you would an `std:mutex`:

```
// Define the mutex
mfc::mutex m;

void foo() { 
    std::lock_guard<mfc::mutex> L(m);
    // use whatever m is protecting
}
```

You may not even need that though. You may have run into the fact that a Windows-native mutex is always a recursive mutex, and a `std::mutex` is not. If you replace it with `std::recursive_mutex` instead of `std::mutex`, it may work just fine (or depending on how you do your locking, you may need a `recursive_timed_mutex`).

Comment: I found that having raw resource with a lightweight, scope protection is superior to wrapping the resource completely if the code needs to interact with C code. It leads to ever-changing interface of the wrapper, and it ends up having sone direct getter to mess with it. But I guess you know better given my experience of one semester.

Comment: @Incomputable: this doesn't give any indication of interacting with C code--MFC is  a C++ library, so the original code was apparently C++.

Comment: sorry, my mind failed me there. I wanted to say “with code that has limited flexibility and codebase has tons of it already”. Perhaps my first comment was misguided by my bad experience with MFC. Even WinAPI was easier to use. Anyway, mixing your answer and Panta’s seem to produce something interesting (e.g. a template mutex on any syncable object).

Comment: @Incomputable: Fair enough. Here I'm mostly working from the fact that he's already made an attempt at replacing CMutex with `std::mutex`, so replacing with `std::recursive_mutex` or `mfc::mutex` is probably about equally easy. He's planning to use something that's at least extremely similar to `std::lock_guard` in any case, so this seems to fit with the chosen plan of attack reasonably well.

Comment: @Jerry That wrapper was my 1st thought as well (IIRC I did such already)

Comment: @JerryCoffin You are right. Replacing `std::mutex` with `std::recursive_mutex` resolves the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather use a reference than a pointer:

```
class CLockGuard {
public:
    CLockGuard::CLockGuard(CMutex& mutex) m_mutex(mutex) {
        m_mutex.Lock();
    }
    ~CLockGuard() {
        m_mutex.Unlock();
    }

    void Unlock() {
        m_mutex.Unlock();
    }

protected:
    CMutex& m_mutex;
};
```

Passing a `nullptr` to the `CLockGuard` class doesn't seem to make much sense to me, unless you want to have runtime control over using a mutex or not.

---

Also you could make it a template (similar as `std::lock_guard`), to be able to operate with any [`CSyncObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c1b9kkf.aspx) descendant:

```
template<typename T>
class CLockGuard {
public:
    CLockGuard::CLockGuard(T& so) m_synchobject(so) {
        m_synchobject.Lock();
    }
    ~CLockGuard() {
        m_synchobject.Unlock();
    }

    void Unlock() {
        m_synchobject.Unlock();
    }

protected:
    T& m_synchobject;
};
```

Comment: References must be initialized. I use `nullptr` assignment as part of the mechanism to prevent multiple `Unlock()` on the mutex. This CLockGuard class has the flexibility to `Unlock()` the mutex just after dealing with the protected resource. Kind of `std::unique_lock` flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I preferred, of course, to use c++11 `std::mutex m_mutex` and
>   `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_mutex)` but it throws an exception.

The original problem solved. The cause was using `std::mutex`; on using `std::recursive_mutex` instead, the project works fine. It seems, mutexes are recursive by default in Windows.